# Can I use the phrase "come true" for "plan"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

As far as I know, the phrase "come true" is used to talk about realization of dreams and wishes, now I am wondering *can I use it for plans, goals, and something like that*? consider the following sentence as an example. Feel free to suggest some other idiom instead. Thank you in advance!

> While according to the announcement the plan would help the university attract more top students, the woman points out that this would not **come true**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plan is more concrete than a dream or wish. Plans *succeed, work out* or *have results.*

You could say "The woman points out that this [that the plan would help] would not necessarily be the case."

Answer (score 0):

I think it is grammatically correct and the phrase can be used in that context. However, it does read slightly awkwardly in the sentence you have. If you want to use an idiom, "come to pass" might also work.